# Discerning this a clause or a phrase?

Tags: phrases, clauses

> **now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain**.

I guess this may contain a verb, *unfolding* and a subject, *themselves* so maybe I may not discern it a phrase. So I guess I may mostly discern it a non-finite subclause (dependent clause[?])? I maybe thought a dependent clause contains a subordinate conjunction or a relative pronoun placed in a first word placement. *unfolding* may seem like a participle. This may somewhat seem like a participle phrase. And I think it contains a verb and subject so maybe not? *now* may seem an adverbial complement to *unfolding* and may get me somewhat.

> ***Now unfolding into limbless monsters of pain***, his thoughts came (hastily[?] (not sure if *came* gets discerned transitive).

This may seem like maybe a participle phrase, no subject *themselves*?

> ***Unfolding into limbless monsters of pain***, his thoughts vexed him.

I think this may mostly seem a participle phrase, (no adverbial complement *now* that may get me), no subject.

Comment: *themselves* is not the subject, but an object. The subject would be the word that this phrase is attached to. Something unfolds something (*themselves*, object) into something (*into limbless...*, prepositional object)

Comment: So *themselves* object, in “And I still have other smothered memories, now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.", like that object *smothered memories*? So I guess may it seem a participle phrase containing a participle(?) *unfolding* that contains *now* an adverbial compliment?

Comment: No, *other smothered memories* is the object in your main clause (And I still have other smothered memories...), but it is the subject in your non-finite subclause (smothered memories, now unfolding...). In that subclause, *themselves* is the object, *now* an adverbial complement, *unfolding* the predicate (verb) and *limbless monsters of pain* a prepositional object.

Comment: A clause consists of multiple phrases. I think you're confusing functions (subject, verb, object etc) with phrases (verb phrase, adjective phrase, noun phrase, ...).

Comment: So a clause may utilize an object of another clause and utilize it like something different? *other smothered memories*, object in main clause, utilizing it in that next clause like a subject? I guess I may not frequently read subclause. I think I read independent (main[?]) clause, dependent clause, relative clause, and noun clause. I may not get prepositional object. I think I get verbs may utilize arguments like subject or maybe if transitive subject and object.

Comment: I guess I think *unfolding* seemed like maybe a present participle so I think I maybe guessed that a participle phrase. I think what seemed and may seem to get me, I think participle phrases function like adjectives, and *now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.* seems to function like a verb placing information on what other smothered memories seems doing *now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.*.

Answer (score 1):

What I call a clause has a subject and a predicate.   This doesn't, so I don't call it a clause.

There is a verb: "unfolding".   This is a non-finite verb.   Without context, there is nothing to establish whether it is a participle or a gerund.   The -ing form could suit either role.

"Themselves" is a pronoun, specifically a reflexive pronoun.   It's the direct object of "unfolding".   "Into limbless monsters of pain" is a prepositional phrase.   It might act as an adverbial adjunct of "unfolding"   It might act as an object complement, making it a predicate adjectival phrase.   For this phrase, I don't know how to distinguish between those possibilities.   The "now" is just a simple adverb.

"Themselves" cannot serve as a subject -- at least, it can't in most dialects.   The subjective form is simply "they".   We use "themselves" as either a reflexive or an intensive form.

As a participial phrase, it can act as the complement of a finite verb.   That is, in fact, the way that we express the continuous aspect in English:

> They are now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.

With the addition of a subject and a finite verb, we have a clause.

As you've already determined, and still as a participial phrase, your example can be used to modify a subject or an object:

> His thoughts, now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain, forced him to run away.
>
> His actions were driven by his thoughts, now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.

In general, -ing forms can also be gerunds.   Unfortunately, I can't think offhand of a natural-sounding sentence which uses your unmodified phrase as a subject or an object.   The reflexive pronoun needs something to reflect.  However:

> Their now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain was quite unexpected.
>
> We can prevent their now unfolding themselves into limbless monsters of pain.